# Estimating the average contiguous sequence length of a balanced boolean function

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, co.combinatorics, boolean-functions

Given a balanced Boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n\mapsto\{0,1\}$, is there a sampling strategy that needs less than $O(2^n)$ samples to estimate the average length of contiguous sequences of 1's?

Balanced means over all possible x's $f(x)=0$ 50% of the time, $f(x)=1$ 50% of the time.

Pointers to background papers related to this topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do you define the average length?

Comment: Because the function is balanced, we know there are 2^(n-1) x_i's such that f(x_i)=1. So the average contiguous sequence length is  equal to the number of 1's divided number of unique contiguous sequences, ie Average = 2^(n-1)/(# of unique contiguous sequences of 1's)

Comment: I think the asker wants to know if the denominator can be approximated with some probability via sampling.